# 18.04.04 Server needs new eth0 driver for networking, help installing

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, gigabyte

Similar to the problems detailed [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244745/ubuntu-20-04-intel-network-connectivity-issue-bug-in-igc),

I have a new-build file server with a Gigabyte Aorus AX Z490 motherboard.

I cannot get this machine to reliably raise network interfaces with eth0 and automatically gain connectivity on every reboot - at least without being physically present to do a hard reboot and inserting the ethernet cable into the back after the boot sequence has finished.

Could I have some handholding through this? I've never installed a linux driver manually before, and apparently the needed driver is not yet included in the 18.04 Server kernel by default. Oddly enough however, it was included when I first loaded 18.04 Desktop version on this machine to run trial tests. There were no connectivity problems under 18.04 Desktop (at least I think it was 18.04 Desktop, and not 20.04 Desktop).

In the posting linked at the top, that user listed out these steps:

> I was able to solve this thanks to your workaround.
>
> I had a different motherboard, so I downloaded the Windows LAN Driver
> from Asus's website at
> https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z490-E-GAMING/HelpDesk_Download/.
>
> I then downloaded the NVM Update Utility at
> https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24769 since it has a Linux
> version.
>
> The name of the file should be similar to FXVL_15F3_ASUS.bin, but the
> ending will be different depending on the various Z490 motherboard
> manufacturers. This can be found on the driver website for the
> specific motherboard you are using.
>
> After unzipping this file, I was left with two zip files,
>
> I225V_End_User_FW_UPDATE.zip
> I225V_Intel_Gigabit_Ethernet_Driver_V1.0.1.4_WIN10_64-bit.zip. I found
> the FXVL_15F3_ASUS.bin in I225V_End_User_FW_UPDATE.zip and copy-pasted
> this file over into the /700Series/Linux_x64/ directory for the NVM
> Update Utility.
>
> Next, we need to find the config file for the i225 driver. After
> unzipping and searching the Asus LAN Driver files, I found the proper
> config settings at config_i225.txt in I225V_End_User_FW_UPDATE.zip.
> Again, the location of the config_i225.txt might vary depending on the
> motherboard manufacturer's LAN driver.
>
> Lastly, I navigated to nvmupdate.cfg in /700Series/Linux_x64/, and
> added this to the end of the file:
>
> BEGIN DEVICE
> DEVICENAME: NNT
> VENDOR:     8086
> DEVICE:     15F3
> SUBVENDOR:  1043
> SUBDEVICE:  87D2
> NVM IMAGE:  FXVL_15F3_ASUS.bin
> IMAGE DOWNGRADE: TRUE END DEVICE Once this is added, type sudo ./nvmupdate64e. After following the on-screen instructions, Ethernet
> should connect immediately. Hope this helps anyone experiencing this
> issue!

Somewhere in this process, I go completely off the rails and get lost. When I try sudo `./nvmupdate64e` nothing happens, so whatever I'm doing wrong comes up prior to that point.

My lspci is as follows:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b53 (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc5 (rev 05)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 06f9
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 06ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 06ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 06f0
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 06e0
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06c0 (rev f0)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06ac (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b8 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0685
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 06c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 06a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 06a4
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 2263 (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15f3 (rev 02)
```

I need the 15f3 Intel ethernet driver for linux, and I have it (per that other thread's postings) but I am too much in the n00b to novice (at best!) understanding with linux drivers to get any further. Anyone able to guide me along?

EDITING to add these:

```
$ dmesg | grep igc
[    1.992521] igc 0000:04:00.0: 4.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth (5 GT/s x1 link)
[    1.992524] igc 0000:04:00.0 eth0: MAC: b4:2e:99:f9:85:e4
[    2.042086] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
[   22.143385] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

/etc/netplan/config.yaml:

```
 network:
     version: 2
     renderer: NetworkManager
     ethernets:
      enp4s0:
       dhcp4: no
       optional: true
       dhcp6: no
       addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
       gateway4: 192.168.1.1
       nameservers:
        addresses: [208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220]
```

I changed the renderer from Networkd to NetworkManager earlier on in this fiasco. It's possible I should change it back. Thanks again.

Edit again, I got a bit further along in the steps listed but am still seeing errors.

```
sudo ./nvmupdate64e

Intel(R) Ethernet NVM Update Tool
NVMUpdate version 1.35.23.3
Copyright (C) 2013 - 2020 Intel Corporation.


WARNING: To avoid damage to your device, do not stop the update or reboot or power off the system during this update.
Inventory in progress. Please wait [|.........]


Num Description                          Ver.(hex)  DevId S:B    Status
=== ================================== ============ ===== ====== ==============
01) Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (2)    1.69(1.45)   15F3 00:004 Update not    
    I225-V                                                       available


Tool execution completed with the following status: Device not found.
Press any key to exit.
```

Edit to add:

```
$ ps aux | grep network
systemd+  1036  0.0  0.0  71880  5232 ?        Ss   Jul07   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
root      1348  0.0  0.1 169100 17012 ?        Ssl  Jul07   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
myusername  10796  0.0  0.0  13132  1032 pts/2    S+   21:54   0:00 grep --color=auto network
```

EDIT 7/9/2020: Got as far as running `sudo ./nvmupdate64e`but this is what keeps happening:

$ sudo ./nvmupdate64e

```
Intel(R) Ethernet NVM Update Tool
NVMUpdate version 1.35.23.3
Copyright (C) 2013 - 2020 Intel Corporation.


WARNING: To avoid damage to your device, do not stop the update or reboot or power off the system during this update.
Inventory in progress. Please wait [|.........]


Num Description                          Ver.(hex)  DevId S:B    Status
=== ================================== ============ ===== ====== ==============
01) Intel(R) Ethernet Controller        1.69(1.45)   15F3 00:004 Update not    
    I225-V                                                       available


Tool execution completed with the following status: Device not found.
Press any key to exit.
```

Any further advice? seems like I'm getting close but it's one stumbling block after another.

Comment: I am not an expert.  BUT have fought similar battles.  My guess is that if you ever had connectivity and can do it manually then the driver is there.  It may get blacklisted after reboot or it may get superseded by another driver that does not work or another connection whose details override it. Step 1. Get it connected as you said you can.  Then gather all the details about it Name, IP etc. Then check your netplan settings in /etc/netplan/something.yaml. See if the network is managed by network manager or netplan.  Report back here.

Comment: You have misread that previous thread. It's NOT that the drivers (actually kernel modules) were missing. The kernel modules were in place and correct. The hardware shipped with buggy firmware, and the answer was about how to update that firmware to a working version.

Comment: "can do it manually then the driver is there" Yes, exactly! Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `dmesg | grep igc` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: Thank you, I have added those two outputs.

Comment: Also, I've gotten a bit further in those above steps. But I'm still getting a message saying the device cannot be found.

Comment: Is this a server or a desktop? Is Network Manager installed and running? `ps aux | grep etwork` If NM is installed and running, in my opinion not correct for a server, especially if it will be running headless, make your settings there. Please clarify. Your dmesg reading don't look abnormal at all. I'd discontinue, at least for now, the NVM update process.

Comment: Hi @chili555, I have edited my post to include the results of ps aux | grep network at the bottom of the posting above. The machine is a headless server. I only use a GUI through a networked Ubuntu desktop. I believe I have network manager active as the renderer for netplan, however for now I am unable to verify that network manager is configured properly. But I do have network connectivity only after hard reboots and re-plugging the ethernet cable to the back after system restart. Looking into discontinuing NVM updates. I cannot risk running a remote reboot because neworking won't come back.

Comment: Also, @chili555, I cannot find evidence that NVM is active or even installed currently.

Answer (score 0):

Please amend, with nano, vim or emacs for example, your /etc/netplan/config.yaml file to this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.2/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220]
```

Reference: https://netplan.io/examples

Netplan is very specific about spacing and indetation. It will accept spaces but not tabs. Proofread carefully twice before you save and exit the text editor.  Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Did you connect?

```
ip addr show
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: Getting these messages:  sudo netplan generate
bind: Address already in use
netplan: fatal error: cannot bind to port 2983, is another daemon running?, exiting.
sudo netplan apply
bind: Address already in use
netplan: fatal error: cannot bind to port 2983, is another daemon running?, exiting. Thanks for tips, @chili555, I may have messed up something prior that is causing this now. I can indeed succesfully ping -c3 www.google.com

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400673 and also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59478507/netplan-error-cannot-bind-to-port-2893-address-is-already-in-use

Comment: Thanks, just went over both links and tried them. Here's what happened: sudo netplan generate; netplan try
ERROR: cannot create file run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp4s0: Failed to create file “/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp4s0.network.IR97M0”: Permission denied
Then I tried entering sudo netplan apply followed by sudo netplan generate and then followed by sudo netplan apply (it didn't want to take following the proper reverse order). Upon reboot I still am getting [FAILED] Failed to raise network interfaces in the bootup process (this isn't new), but now also...

Comment: ...but also [FAILED] Failed to start netfilter persistent configuration (that's a new twist). It didn't autoraise the network on boot, but it still got on the Internet after a hard reboot and a reinsertion of the ethernet cable at the back of the box after the full boot up process completed. Any further help is appreciated. I am sorry to do this to any of you.

Comment: Added an edit from Thurs night 7/9 at the bottom, wondering what to do now

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://www.toontricks.com/2017/06/ubuntu-failed-to-start-netfilter.html You seem to have made a lot of tweaks and changes that are causing trouble. Is a fresh reinstall a possibiity?