# My Lan connection is not working

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, 20.04, lan

I gathered a desktop. And I installed ubuntu 20.04. I opened it and everything was okay. Then i installed nvidia-driver 440, then reboot. When i opened the computer, My lan connection is not working.
My motherboard: Asus rog strix z490-a gaming

I guess, it may be about motherboard driver. Has anyone idea?

```
sudo lshw -C network   *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 01
       serial: d4:5d:64:b3:d5:40
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=0.0.1-k latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:81100000-811fffff memory:81200000-81203fff
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give the Pop!_OS kernel a try for the Intel I225-V Ethernet Controller.  I have the same NIC on the Asus ROG-STRIX-B550-I.  I was running the 5.4.0-42-generic kernel under Ubuntu, and the NIC would not come up.  On 5.4.0-7634-generic distributed by Pop, the NIC works.  It looks like Pop is using a more up to date branch of the igc driver for kernel 5.4.  However, I have noticed that the igc driver still has bugs in kernel 5.4. For instance, the /proc/net/dev stats are blank and do not update under the igc driver for the NIC.

Add the Pop repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop
```

Do an `apt update`, and apt should recommend to upgrade the kernel to the Pop version.

As an aside, I actually switched kernels by accident when I added the Pop ppa to get their icons under Xubuntu.

I did try compiling the latest source for the igc driver in the 5.8 kernel.  And it is a no go for 5.4.  It looks like the 5.8 kernel adds some power management dependencies that are lacking in 5.4.

Another option is to upgrade the firmware on the NIC. [Others](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244745/ubuntu-20-04-intel-network-connectivity-issue-bug-in-igc) have had success doing this.  I have not tried this option b/c Asus has not provided any firmware updates for my particular B550 motherboard.

Comment: I use a Wi-fi adapter. And I don't have a Lan connection.  If i connect to LAN, i will try it. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the Xanmod kernel. Available at: https://xanmod.org/

The latest stable is the 5.8.x branch (at time of post) Xanmod also have an LTS version (5.4.x) and a (bleeding) edge version.

If you stick with their 'stable' release though it is supported by the xanmod community and widely used.