# Ubuntu 20.04 No Internet (eth/wifi noting...)

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, intel

I have been searching for days trying to figure this problem out and I have absolutely no luck.

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an external HDD. I got the no wifi adapter issue. I ran:

```
lshw -C Network
```

and I got (attached photo): [lshw -c network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCksb.jpg)

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with my PC. Specs are:

12900k CPU

Gigabyte z690 Aero G DDR4

Intel® 2.5GbE LAN chip (2.5 Gbps/1 Gbps/100 Mbps)

Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201

I have Windows 10 installed and it works like a charm. Wifi and ethernet. I have reinstalled Ubuntu several times and the same thing happens. I have no idea what to do and any help would be appreciated. I am quite a novice when it comes to all things computers and electronics.

Thank you.

Comment: Try 21.10 instead. Your network hardware is newer than the release you installed.

Comment: Please don't attach screenshots of text, especially terminal output. It's very difficult for us to work with (a photo of a screen is even worse due to glare, angles, cropping, and moire). Instead, copy/paste and format your post using [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to preserve monospace formatting and line breaks. Just put three back ticks on the line before and three back ticks on the line after blocks of text copy/pasted from your terminal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses! Sorry, I am messaging from my phone as my desktop doesn't have internet so I just thought the photo would be quicker. @ChanganAuto will there be a big difference between 21.10 and 20.04? If there any way to get 20.04 to work on my hardware? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Native hardware support is kernel dependent. Your hardware requires a newer kernel. 20.04 will catch up eventually. But really I don't see the point. You can try and install 21.10 now and in April next year upgrade to 22.04 LTS.

Comment: @changanauto thanks again so much. Just so I understand better, there are no drivers that I can download to install? I have to wait for newer kernel? Thanks again, I will do as you suggested and get 21.10.

Comment: Using the information you already gathered it's easy to search this site. There are some options if I'm remembering correctly but it's often suggested to use a newer kernel.

Comment: @ChanganAuto
OK, I just installed 21.10 and I'm still having the same issues. Any other thoughts? Do I need to install drivers from somewhere? I'm really at a loss here. Thank you.

Comment: Again, I suggest you search this site with the network devices' names. There are already some Q&As about both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me on MSI Z690 EDGE WiFi DDR4, so it is due to lack of drivers for those NICs I think.
Have you checked this topic? It seems to have the answer
[Ubuntu 20.04 Intel Network connectivity issue, bug in igc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244745/ubuntu-20-04-intel-network-connectivity-issue-bug-in-igc)
Links to those drivers: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/15084/intel-ethernet-adapter-complete-driver-pack.html?

Comment: Thank you @Arwinnd! I am looking through this thread now. Were you able to solve the issue? Everything works for you now? Were you having issues with wifi adapter as well? Thank you for your response

Comment: I'm not using now WIFI, but I will have issues with WIFI hmm... I think, maybe I will check. For now my issue is not resolved, as I tried it only for a short while. Maybe I will try again today.

Comment: thanks. Any luck? Does your ethernet work? Are you able to connect to the internet at all? I am a little confused about the directions from the post that you linked. Do you know anyone from that post? I wish I could just dm them.

Comment: Hi, I thought to myself why I should bother with custom driver installations? Manjaro has easy to use tool to change kernel. So I did change it, and now it works flawlessly :) 

Currently running: 5.15.2-2-MANJARO (linux515) works for me