# Intel AX201 Wi-Fi 6 and Ethernet Won't Work Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, ethernet, 21.10

I posted a similar question but I'm trying to expand it because I have now tried both versions and still can't seem to get anything to work. I've looked through about 20 different pages and have tried a host of different suggestions but still can't seem to get this to work. I'm very new to linux and not nearly as technically inclined as a lot of you in the community. Any help would be appreciated.

12900k CPU

Gigabyte z690 Aero G DDR4

Intel® 2.5GbE LAN chip (2.5 Gbps/1 Gbps/100 Mbps)

Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201

I have Fastboot disabled and I have safeboot disabled as well. Windows 10 works without a hiccup so far. I tried updating the firmware but that didn't seem to resolve the issue either. I will attempt to investigate the netplan .yaml file again.

My friend thinks that it may have something to do with the kernel module, but that is going deep into territory that neither of us are experienced in.

Please let me know what you would like for me to post and I will start from the beginning.

*Response to @chili555:
When I input

`sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

there is no output.

I have not modified the .yaml file yet

Edit #2

@Chili555

```
lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3
```

results with output:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7af0] (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7acc] (rev 11)
--
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15f3] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:e000]
    Kernel modules: igc
```

And when I input:

`modinfo iwlwifi`

I get about 200+ lines of output

Thank you again @chili555

Edit #3

I ran:

```
modinfo iwlwifi | grep 7AF0
```

which resulted with

```
alias:          pci:v00008086d00007AF0sv*sd00000A10bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00007AF0sv*sd00000510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00007AF0sv*sd00000310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00007AF0sv*sd000000B0bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00007AF0sv*sd00000098bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00007AF0sv*sd00000090bc*sc*i*
```

when I ran:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

I had no output. Same with

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Thank again.

edit # 4

Ran a live session from USB and ran

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

output was:

```
    [   12.805748] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.809293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809341] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809386] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-61.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809430] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809517] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809557] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809597] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809718] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809757] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809797] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809837] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809915] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.809992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.810030] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.810067] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.810105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.810142] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.810179] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.810217] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.810255] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[   12.810257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[   12.810259] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39
[   12.810260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63
[   12.810261] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Edit #5

Happy Thanksgiving to those who celebrate it. I ran:

```
uname -r
```

and the output was:

```
5.13.0-19-generic
```

and I ran

```
ls /usr/lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0
```

and the output was

```
iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode
```

Comment: "I will attempt to investigate the netplan .yaml file again." Have you modified it in some way? If not, please do not. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This is the same as your other question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376486/ubuntu-20-04-no-internet-eth-wifi-noting

Comment: @chili555
I did as you instructed and I posted the edits. I have not changed the .yaml file yet. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. I was looking through a similar issue that you were helping with, but I was unable to get a successful result for some reason. I must be doing something wrong. Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Let's dig a bit deeper. May we please see: `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3` and tell me if there is any output from the command: `modinfo iwlwifi` I needn't see the whole thing; just tell us if you got 200+ lines of output or if you got an error. If an error, please post it.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you again for responding. I did as you instructed and posted edited in my message. Please let me know what you need next. Someone just sent me this link:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244745/ubuntu-20-04-intel-network-connectivity-issue-bug-in-igc I am looking through this thread, but I will not do anything until I hear back from you. Thank you

Comment: Please run: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 7AF0` Note that 7af0 is part of the pci.id for your wireless device. If you get results, then your kernel version and driver support your device. Next, run: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` If there are any errors, edit your question to include them. If no errors, please show us: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 Thanks again. I did as instructed and shared the results in the edit.

Comment: Ahh, haaa!! Your subsystem 0074 is not listed, The subsystems 0090, 0098, et al are covered, but not 0074. Studying. What is your kernel version? `uname -r` I suspect that running 5.13.0-xx might help.

Comment: Hi @chili555 , the current kernal is: 5.11.0-40-generic. Would you be able to help walk me through how to safely update kernal? Although I had same issue on 21.10 and I think kernal was newer but still same issue. Thanks again so much

Comment: Please run a live session from a USB or DVD of 21.10 and run `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and show us the result.

Comment: @chili555 I did as requested and edited my question to show the result. Thank you again. I am very grateful for you taking the time to try and help me.

Comment: Fascinating! Although the message suggests that we consult kernel.org for firmware, the only appropriate firmware there is -64. The dmesg says you need -63 or older! My 21.10 system only holds -64. What does the live USB say about this? `uname -r` and also: `ls /usr/lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0` ?

Comment: Hi @chili555. Happy Thanksgiving if you celebrate it. I am thankful for you and your help. I ran the inputs as instructed and edited my question to reflect outputs.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error:

```
[   12.810257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[   12.810259] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39
[   12.810260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63
```

After downloading firmware from [linux-firmware](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/): [iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode) WiFi works without problems.

In case someone has AX201 but does not see mentioned errors in logs, use newest kernel you can find. For me only **5.16** version did work (5.15 did not work). You can find one here: [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16-rc7/amd64/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16-rc7/amd64/) :

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16-rc7/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.0-051600rc7-generic_5.16.0-051600rc7.202112262230_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16-rc7/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.0-051600rc7_5.16.0-051600rc7.202112262230_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16-rc7/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.16.0-051600rc7-generic_5.16.0-051600rc7.202112262230_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16-rc7/amd64/linux-modules-5.16.0-051600rc7-generic_5.16.0-051600rc7.202112262230_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

linux-headers installation may fail due to dependencies, but the kernel itself installs.

Solution based on polish Ubuntu forum post by mario_7: https://ubuntu.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?t=185951

Comment: I can confirm doing this upgrade (in spite of warning messages saying this was a "partial update") and some errors, fixed the issue after reboot. I went from `5.13` to `5.16`

Answer (score 1):

I have searched many places and many resources for the required but not found firmware files iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-XX.ucode where XX is any number from 39 to 63 inclusive. From your dmesg:

```
[   12.810257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[   12.810259] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39
[   12.810260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63
[   12.810261] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

I have been unable to find any. I therefore have only two suggestions. First, try to trick the driver by renaming the -64 version you do have:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode  iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
```

Reboot. Check:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Is the firmware error resolved? Does the wireless work as expected?

My last suggestion is to file a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu Include the dmesg log from above.

Comment: Thank you @chili555. Since I am running a live session, will the renaming me saved when I reboot? When I did as instructed I received the same output. Thank you.

Comment: Running in live session will not survive a reboot. Run the command to copy (rename) the firmware file and do: `sud modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and then check: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help. No resolution. I will file bug report and be sad. Thank you so much for trying to help me @chili555

Comment: changing the name from 64 to 63 did not help me either