# WiFi and Bluetooth doesn't work for Intel AX201 in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, 21.10

My desktop is
i9 - 12900
GeForce RTX3080
ASUS Z690-PLUS WIFI D4 (Intel AX201 WiFi + integrated Bluetooth)

Just a fresh installation of Ubuntu 21.10.
Both WiFi and Bluetooth doesn't work for me.

What should be my route to get them working?

Would appreciate any advise!

Edit #1
Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

> 00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device
> [8086:7af0] (rev 11)  DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet  Subsystem: Intel
> Corporation Device [8086:0074]    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Output of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

> [    4.025078] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
>
> [    4.027423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027550] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027563] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-61.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-60.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027752] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-58.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027917] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027929] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-54.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-53.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.027968] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-52.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028118] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-51.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028132] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028151] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028161] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-47.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028170] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028180] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-45.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-44.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028201] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-43.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028210] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-42.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028220] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-41.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-40.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028238] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.028239] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
>
> [    4.028241] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required:
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39
>
> [    4.028243] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported:
> iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63
>
> [    4.028244] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check
> git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

Comment: I think your WiFi+BT is supported in 5.15 kernel or newer.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Added outputs  of commands you specified. Thank you!

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377110/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-and-ethernet-wont-work-ubuntu-20-04-and-21-10/1377741#1377741 You have the exact same symptoms and I regret that there is currently no solution. I recommend that you file a bug report. I am unable to find the report that @Boont said would be filed.

Comment: Yes, that’s the same problem. I tried to use mainline kernel 5.15+ and everything works great there, but system doesn’t power off. In kernels 5.14 - Wi-Fi would work, but Bluetooth wouldn’t, restart would work. Do you probably have any suggestions how to fix power off functionality? So I can reboot my desktop when needed? I played with GRUB settings with no luck

Comment: Power off is outside of my limited experience and skill. I suggest you ask a new question specifically about power off. Sorry.