# Intel Wireless Adapter suddenly not working - Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I have a Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 wifi adapter that is suddenly not working after a reboot. None of the existing askubuntu solutions help me with my issue.

I have found an error code in the logs that I would like to diagnose:

```
[ 2.149266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[ 2.162835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[ 2.162852] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[ 2.163139] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[ 2.402444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
[ 3.435257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5881, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[ 3.435305] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc008097e
[ 3.435314] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x149e6
[ 3.435316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[ 3.436400] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
[ 3.436402] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[ 3.436403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[ 3.436404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[ 3.436405] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[ 3.436406] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[ 3.436407] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[ 3.436408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[ 3.436409] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[ 3.436410] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[ 3.436411] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[ 3.436412] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[ 3.436413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[ 3.436414] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 3.436415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[ 3.436416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[ 3.436417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[ 3.436417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[ 3.436418] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[ 3.436419] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[ 3.436420] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[ 3.436421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[ 3.436422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[ 3.436423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[ 3.436424] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[ 3.436425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 3.436426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[ 3.436427] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[ 3.436427] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[ 3.436428] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[ 3.436429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 3.436430] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[ 3.436431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 3.436432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[ 3.436433] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[ 3.436469] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 3.436470] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[ 3.436471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[ 3.436473] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 3.436474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8045544E | umac branchlink2
[ 3.436475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047395A | umac interruptlink1
[ 3.436476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00834C2 | umac interruptlink2
[ 3.436476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[ 3.436478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00834C2 | umac data2
[ 3.436479] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[ 3.436479] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003F | umac major
[ 3.436480] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC04F3485 | umac minor
[ 3.436481] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000F8C8C | frame pointer
[ 3.436482] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F28 | stack pointer
[ 3.436483] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[ 3.436484] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000004 | isr status reg
[ 3.436502] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[ 3.436503] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[ 3.436510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005881 | IML/ROM data1
[ 3.436517] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[ 3.436522] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[ 3.436525] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000021 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 3.436527] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 3.436530] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 3.436532] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 3.436535] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 3.436537] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 3.436540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 3.436542] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 3.436545] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 3.436549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 3.436554] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 3.436558] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 3.436561] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 3.436563] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[ 4.282401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Search for "AX201" here on AU and you'll find your answer.

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? Is Fast Boot turned off? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: This is not dual boot. Fast boot is also turned off. Unfortunately looking up AX201 on AU hasn't helped me so far.

Comment: Please try upgrading to kernel version 5.15: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377110/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-and-ethernet-wont-work-ubuntu-20-04-and-21-10

Comment: I updated to 5.15 but unfortunately still get `[    7.834573] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110`. It does seem to try initialising twice now though with `retry init count 2`

Comment: Does it still load the -63 version of the firmware? `sudo dmesg | grep firm`

Comment: Yes it does - `[    7.294605] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Ubuntu package linux-firmware for 22.04, a testing release, also contains firmware versions -66, -67 and -68. Let's install them and see if the wireless now works.

Please open a terminal and do:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-67.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-68.ucode
```

Also, on the chance that the current firmware version -63 is somehow corrupted, let's install a fresh copy:

```
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I stuggled with this and tried all the suggestions ... then as soon as I did this it and rebooted it worked!

Edit :
/etc/default/grub

From :
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

To:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"

Run:
sudo update-grub

Reboot =)